# How to sort elements in array of strings by regex pattern matching

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, sorting, vue.js

I have an object

What I want to achieve, is get every 1st level key name as a string and put those strings grouped into new arrays, each array for specific group.
Then, sort each group array according to the order of the matches inside of each regex pattern.

What I currently have, is code which groups strings into new arrays, but without sorting them when in arrays.

What I currently get is:

```
["firstName", "lastName", "birthDate", "birthPlace", "fatherName", "identityCard", "pesel", "passportNo", "passportExpirationDate", "citizenship"] // output of generalSectionElements
```

but what I want is to have the array already sorted, so `citizenship` string should be right after `fatherName` and not at the end of the array.
Just like the order of matches inside above regex pattern.

I'm sure it's possible, but can't wrap my mind around that, anyone can at least give me some hint(s)? :/

```js
const generalSectionPattern = /^(fir|las|(?=\w+D)bir\w+|(?=\w+P)bir\w+|fat|cit|ide|pes|(?=\w+N)pas\w+|(?=\w+E)pas\w+)/
const contactSectionPattern = /^(ema|mob|pre)/
const positionSectionPattern = /^(pos)/
const editorialSectionPattern = /((?!\w+Phone)edi\w*|(?=\w+Phone)edi\w*|fax)/
const flightSectionPattern = /^(bus|car|par|hot|pla|tra|des)/

const generalSectionElements = Object.keys(myObj).filter(elem => generalSectionPattern.test(elem))

console.log(generalSectionElements)
```

```html
<script>
const myObj = { 
  "firstName":              { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": true  }, 
  "lastName":               { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": true  }, 
  "editorialOffice":        { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": true  }, 
  "email":                  { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": true  }, 
  "birthDate":              { "fieldType": "DATE",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": true  }, 
  "birthPlace":             { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": false }, 
  "fatherName":             { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": true  }, 
  "identityCard":           { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": true  }, 
  "bothDocuments": false, 
  "pesel":                  { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": true }, 
  "passportNo":             { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": false }, 
  "passportExpirationDate": { "fieldType": "DATE",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": false }, 
  "pressCardNumber":        { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": true  }, 
  "editorialOfficePhone":   { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": true  }, 
  "fax":                    { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": false }, 
  "mobilePhone":            { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": true  },
  "position":               { "fieldType": "RADIO",  "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": true  }, 
  "citizenship":            { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": true  }, 
  "plane":                  { "fieldType": "SELECT", "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": false }, 
  "bus":                    { "fieldType": "SELECT", "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": false }, 
  "hotel":                  { "fieldType": "SELECT", "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": false },
   "transmission":          { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": false }, 
  "parking":                { "fieldType": "SELECT", "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": false }, 
  "carInfo":                { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": false }, 
  "statement":              { "fieldType": "TEXT",   "value": null, "enabled": true, "required": true  }, 
  "descriptiveFields": [
    { "fieldType": "RADIO",    "value": null, "enabled": false, "required": false }, 
    { "fieldType": "TEXTAREA", "value": null, "enabled": false, "required": false }, 
    { "fieldType": "TEXT",     "value": null, "enabled": false, "required": false } 
  ] 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you happen to be aware of [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)?

Comment: Please see the snippet I wrote for you. It is MUCH MORE USEFUL and readable

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov yes, I'm aware, but couldn't figure out what to compare, inside comparator function.

Comment: Wouldn't `sort()`'ing without parameters your current output work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, browsing through docs for JS Array at Mozilla Developer Network, I've tested out the solution for my problem.

Here's the code

```js
const myObj = {
  "firstName": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": true
  },
  "lastName": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": true
  },
  "editorialOffice": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": true
  },
  "email": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": true
  },
  "birthDate": {
    "fieldType": "DATE",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": true
  },
  "birthPlace": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": false
  },
  "fatherName": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": true
  },
  "identityCard": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": true
  },
  "bothDocuments": false,
  "pesel": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": true
  },
  "passportNo": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": false
  },
  "passportExpirationDate": {
    "fieldType": "DATE",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": false
  },
  "pressCardNumber": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": true
  },
  "editorialOfficePhone": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": true
  },
  "fax": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": false
  },
  "mobilePhone": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": true
  },
  "position": {
    "fieldType": "RADIO",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": true
  },
  "citizenship": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": true
  },
  "plane": {
    "fieldType": "SELECT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": false
  },
  "bus": {
    "fieldType": "SELECT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": false
  },
  "hotel": {
    "fieldType": "SELECT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": false
  },
  "transmission": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": false
  },
  "parking": {
    "fieldType": "SELECT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": false
  },
  "carInfo": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": false
  },
  "statement": {
    "fieldType": "TEXT",
    "value": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "required": true
  },
  "descriptiveFields": [{
      "fieldType": "RADIO",
      "value": null,
      "enabled": false,
      "required": false
    },
    {
      "fieldType": "TEXTAREA",
      "value": null,
      "enabled": false,
      "required": false
    },
    {
      "fieldType": "TEXT",
      "value": null,
      "enabled": false,
      "required": false
    }
  ]
}

const generalSectionPatterns = [/^(fir)/, /^(las)/, /^((?=\w+D)bir\w+)/, /^((?=\w+P)bir\w+)/, /^(fat)/, /^(cit)/, /^(ide)/, /^(pes)/, /^((?=\w+N)pas\w+)/, /^((?=\w+E)pas\w+)/]
const contactSectionPatterns = [/^(ema)/, /^(mob)/, /^(pre)/]
const positionSectionPatterns = [/^(pos)/]
const editorialSectionPatterns = [/^((?!\w+Phone)edi\w*)/, /^((?=\w+Phone)edi\w*)/, /^(fax)/]
const flightSectionPatterns = [/^(bus)/, /^(car)/, /^(par)/, /^(hot)/, /^(pla)/, /^(tra)/, /^(des)/]

const generalSectionElements = generalSectionPatterns.map(pattern => Object.keys(myObj).find(elem => pattern.test(elem)))
console.log('sorted generalSectionElements:\n', generalSectionElements)

const contactSectionElements = contactSectionPatterns.map(pattern => Object.keys(myObj).find(elem => pattern.test(elem)))
console.log('sorted contactSectionElements:\n', contactSectionElements)

const positionSectionElements = positionSectionPatterns.map(pattern => Object.keys(myObj).find(elem => pattern.test(elem)))
console.log('sorted positionSectionElements:\n', positionSectionElements)

const editorialSectionElements = editorialSectionPatterns.map(pattern => Object.keys(myObj).find(elem => pattern.test(elem)))
console.log('sorted editorialSectionElements:\n', editorialSectionElements)

const flightSectionElements = flightSectionPatterns.map(pattern => Object.keys(myObj).find(elem => pattern.test(elem)))
console.log('sorted flightSectionElements:\n', flightSectionElements)
```

You can live test the code at [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/WigglyWhitesmokeSort) also.

Second solution is to use [regex-sort](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/regex-sort):

```
function regexSort(list, patterns) {
  function presetIndex(input) {
    for (var i = 0; i < patterns.length; ++i) {
      if (patterns[i].test(input)) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return Infinity;
  }

  let indexes = list.map(c => ({
    input: c,
    index: presetIndex(c)
  }));

  indexes.sort(
    (a, b) => a.index < b.index ? -1 : 1
  );

  return indexes.map(c => c.input);
};
```

The third is problably combining some of the Array methods with .sort(), but as I've written above, didn't figured out what precisely to compare inside sort's comparator function...

Thank you for interest in my problem anyway and giving me any reply at all!
Cheers!